# Reading and manipulating data with arraylists or other data structures

Tags: java, collections

I have a program that reads a file, but I need my program to read the file a certain way. 
Here is how the file that the program reads look like:

```
Sample ID   Date    Time    Elem    Conc (Samp) Samp Units
381220-1    11/17/2014  7:14:57 PM  Y       %
381220-1    11/17/2014  7:14:57 PM  Ge      %
381220-1    11/17/2014  7:14:57 PM  Ge      %
381220-1    11/17/2014  7:14:57 PM  Al  0.008739442 mg/L
381220-1    11/17/2014  7:14:57 PM  As  0.006080418 mg/L
381220-1    11/17/2014  7:14:57 PM  B   0.016079117 mg/L
381220-1    11/17/2014  7:14:57 PM  Ba  -0.000985422    mg/L
381220-1    11/17/2014  7:14:57 PM  Be  -0.00025851 mg/L
381220-1    11/17/2014  7:14:57 PM  Ca  -0.012101454    mg/L
381220-1    11/17/2014  7:14:57 PM  Cd  -0.001148811    mg/L
381220-1    11/17/2014  7:14:57 PM  Ce  -0.045899969    mg/L
381220-2    11/17/2014  7:14:57 PM  Al  2.007892442 mg/L
381220-2    11/17/2014  7:14:57 PM  As  2.006080418 mg/L
```

I need my program to get the SampleID for example 381220-1 and get all the elements (Y,Ge, As, etc.) in one line with the result/value so it should look like this.

```
381220-1, Al, 0.008739442, mg/L, As, 0.006080418, mg/L, etc.  
381220-2, Al, 0.008739442, mg/L, As, 2.006080418, mg/L, etc.
```

I have tried different ways of approaching this, but still can`t get it.
Here is what I have done.

```
try{
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("381220.csv"));
        BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("381220.csv"));
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("file.txt", false);
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);    

        String line = null;
        String line2 = null;
        String[] value = null;
        String[] value2 = null;

        ArrayList<String> Queuelist = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> lineoftxt = new ArrayList<String>();



        while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
            if(line.contains("Sample")){
                continue;
            }

            value = line.split(","); 
            int k = 0;
            for(String S : value){             
                //System.out.println("Value ["+k+"] = " + S);
                k++;
            } 

            Queuelist.add(value[0]+",");

        }

        for(String s : Queuelist){ 
            //System.out.println(s); 
        }



        br.close();   
        pw.close();


        Queuelist = new ArrayList<String>(new LinkedHashSet<String>(Queuelist));

        Set<String> toRetain = new TreeSet<String>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
        toRetain.addAll(Queuelist);
        Set<String> set = new LinkedHashSet<String>(Queuelist);
        set.retainAll(new LinkedHashSet<String>(toRetain));
        Queuelist = new ArrayList<String>(set);

        for(String s : Queuelist){
            //System.out.println(s);
        }

        while((line2 = br2.readLine()) != null){ 
            if(line2.contains("Sample") || line2.contains("Y") || line2.contains("Ge")){
                continue;
            }

            value2 = line2.split(","); 
            int k = 0;
            for(String S : value2){               
                //System.out.println("Value ["+k+"] = " + S);
                k++;
            } 

            lineoftxt.add(line2);

            if(Queuelist.get(0).contains(lineoftxt.get(0))){
                System.out.println(Queuelist.get(0)+","+lineoftxt.get(0));
            }



        } 




        for(String s : lineoftxt){
            //System.out.println(s);
        }


        br2.close();  
        }
    catch(IOException e){}
```

Any suggestions to guide me through this. 
Thanks!

Comment: Since your file is pretty much a csv with spaces as separators you should have good results with csv parser

Comment: @MarcinSzymczak that's not OP's main problem.

Comment: Take a look at the StringTokenizer class, this may help.

Comment: @stanfordude from [`StringTokenizer` javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html): *`StringTokenizer` is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the `split` method of `String` or the `java.util.regex` package instead*

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class `Whatever` which has `final String id;` and a `List<WhateverDetail> detailList` for the rest of the data to group. Use a `Map<String, Whatever>` to group all the `Whatever`s per id, recover an existing `Whatever` instance in case the id was registered and fill a new instance of `WhateverDetail` to add in `detailList`.

Comment: Could you explain a little more or show me an example if you can. I am new working with collections